# Pairwise shortest distance between points in a road network

Tags: shapefile, r, graph, distance-matrix

**1. Problem**

I have the coordinates for over 5000 points (cities) that lie over a road shape file, as partially illustrated below:

[image]

I'm working on R, and **I need to find the shortest distance between all pairs of points along the roads**.

**2. What I've already tried**, without success:

- `stplanr` package: had a problem converting the full road shape file to a `SpatialLinesNetwork` object ("*non finite line lengths*");
- `osrm` package: can't compute all distance pairs (over 30 million) due to server restrictions (up to 10k pairs).

**3. Sample data**

I provide a sample data here: https://github.com/cassianord/example_data/blob/main/example_data.7z?raw=true

Comment: `sl = rgdal::readOGR(".","roads_ex") ; sln = SpatialLinesNetwork(sl)` works for me with no warnings or errors about non finite line lengths. Version 0.8.1 of stplanr.

Comment: Yes, in the sample data that might work, but with the full shape it doesn't =/

Comment: Can you supply a subset where it doesn't work? If we knew where your "non-finite line length" lines were.... Is it simply lines that are length zero and could be dropped anyway?

Comment: Sure, sorry for not doing it before. Here follows a larger sample where the issue happens: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nt0WWSb0pOgRcS4pGOHrR1S3sO0lkgSF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @cassianord. What's the CRS of the data? 4326?

Comment: Hi, @agila! Yes, 4326.

Comment: Is this the entire street map of Brasil? If you want to do 30,000,000 routes and each one takes 1 second that it going to take a year.

Comment: Not all streets, just highways. I'd imagined that it might take a long time to compute, depending on the method. `osrm::osrmTable`, though, provide fast results (about 2 seconds to a thousand routes), but the public server can't run more than 10k routes. I've also tried to loop over `osrmTable`, but the loop breaks with any server lag/error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one row of your roads is causing this error when SpatialLinesNetwork tries to get its length:

```
> SpatialLinesLengths(l[65403,])
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : non-finite line lengths
```

This row appears to have zero length, which is messing up the length calculation when it is using lat-long coordinates:

```
> l[65403,]
class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
features    : 1 
extent      : -41.98302, -41.98302, -15.25437, -15.25437  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

I suspect a divide-by-zero somewhere when working out the distance on a sphere by lat-long.

The adjacent segments are fine:

```
> SpatialLinesLengths(l[65402,])
[1] 1.813751
> SpatialLinesLengths(l[65404,])
[1] 1.802447
```

You can trick it into *not* using lat-long coordinates - there is an option but I think having a CRS on the lines overrides this anyway. So set the CRS to nothing:

```
> proj4string(l) = ""
```

And then I can build a spatial lines network without errors:

```
> ln = SpatialLinesNetwork(l)
>
```

But that will give you a spatial network based on euclidean lat-long distance which might not be very valid.

Or you could project to an appropriate cartesian grid system for your data and use that.

Alternatively you could try an eliminate these rows from your data, but in some cases it seems to be caused by zero-length segments within road segments, which is hard to track down.

Comment: Thanks, @Spacedman, it solved the issue with the `SpatialLinesNetwork`. Now I'm facing other problems in attributing nodes to the network... also, I think that, after all, maybe `stplanr` will not help me to find the distances between all pairs. Nevertheless, I have upvoted your answer and accepted it. Thanks again!